# PREG_REPLACE if string ends with char X, then the last X character replace it with a Y character

Tags: php, regex

If a string ends with the `character X`, i want to replace that particular character with the `character Y`.

**Example 1**

```
anything_number_alphabet_dashes_anythingX[END OF STRING]
```

to

```
anything_number_alphabet_dashes_anythingY[END OF STRING]
```

**Example 2**

```
DontReplaceThis_X_JustOnlyThisLast_X[END OF STRING]
```

to

```
DontReplaceThis_X_JustOnlyThisLast_Y[END OF STRING]
```

I want to do this in PHP with `preg_replace` or `ereg_replace`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dollar sign is the end of string anchor, so:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/X$/', 'Y', $old_str);
```

Comment: Yup that's perfectly correct, thank you Alex Howansky, everytime i'm going to start learning REGEX, i end up here... Stackoverflow will never let me learn REGEX on my own! (i ll accept this answer as soon as time limit ends)

Comment: @easy_weezy: http://regular-expressions.info/ - best reference I've found for general regex. There's also a handful of regex tester websites out there (personal favorite is http://regexpal.com/, although it doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind).

Comment: See also: http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/regular_expressions_cheat_sheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you Nightfirecat and Alex Howansky, this is great material for someone who wants to start learning REGEX.

Comment: Excuse me for re-commenting, but in case a regex-newbie is reading this, i can tell you that pdf file Alex Howansky posted, http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/regular_expressions_cheat_sheet.pdf really worths the downloading AND printing. Thank you again, this question is resolved :)